# explicitly call managed destructor from unmanaged c++

Tags: c++, .net, interop, destruction

I have a native C++ project that makes use of .NET charting utilities through a wrapper class. A cut-down version of the wrapper class is something like this;

```
class ChartWrapper
{
private:
    gcroot<ChartNamespace::ManagedChartClass^>* m_Chart;

public:
    ChartWrapper(): m_Chart(new gcroot<ChartNamespace::ManagedChartClass^>)
    {
        *m_Chart = gcnew ChartNamespace::ManagedChartClass;
    }

    ~ChartWrapper()
    {
        delete m_Chart;
    }

    // Methods to interact with the chart
}
```

A function will take care of instantiating, manipulating, and deleting the chart through the wrapper;

```
void CreateChart()
{
    ChartWrapper* chart = new ChartWrapper();
    // Do stuff to the chart
    delete chart;
}
```

There is the potential of creating hundreds of charts during the program instance. I explicitly delete each wrapper by calling `delete` when I am done with it, but the managed object `ManagedChartClass` is only destructed when the program exits. This causes memory to build up that is not needed and I get 'out of memory' exceptions.

How can I ensure that the managed objects are destructed when the wrapper is destructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`auto_gcroot<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177051.aspx), instead of `gcroot<T>`.  The difference is that `auto_gcroot<T>`'s [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177051.aspx) "also destructs the owned object."

In the managed world, this maps through to calling `IDisposable.Dispose()` on the wrapped managed type, provided it implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Thanks Reed! That solved our memory issues and everything is running smoothly. For anyone else who has tripped over with changing this implementation; gcroot<> is in the global namespace, whereas auto_gcroot<> is in the msclr namespace, so has to be implemented with msclr::auto_gcroot<>. That caused me a headache for a while!!